# Get last value in multiple rows MYSQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table that I use to record the activity log of an application. Now I have to get all records from entity X that have been published in some range of dates. So if a record has been published and later unpublished, it doesn't have to appear in the results.

I don't know how to explain it really, it's find the last appearance of each one and then catch values that are "1" or "0", on depends that I need in each case.

A simplified example (the real table has more fields and more data):

```
id  user_id date         model main_relation_id field   new_value
1   24      2017-03-21   A     1               publish 1
2   24      2017-03-21   A     2               publish 1
3   24      2017-03-22   A     3               publish 0
4   24      2017-03-22   A     2               update  some text
5   24      2017-03-23   A     1               publish 0
6   24      2017-03-23   A     1               update  some text
7   24      2017-03-24   A     3               publish 1
8   24      2017-03-24   A     2               publish 0
9   24      2017-03-24   A     2               update  some text
10  24      2017-03-25   A     1               publish 1
11  24      2017-03-25   A     2               publish 1
11  24      2017-03-26   A     3               publish 0
```

I need to get main_relation_id, filtering by model and date, so if I want to get all registers from model A that have been published between 2017-03-21 and 2017-03-24 I'll get:

```
model_main_relation_id
1 
3
```

and if I want to get all registers that have been unpublished in the same dates, the result have to be:

```
model_main_relation_id
2
```

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you would like to filter on the latest status by `main_relation_id`, whether the particular `main_relation_id` has been published (`field='publish'; new_value=1`) or unpublished (`field='publish'; new_value=0`) within a period.

Since the dates within the `date` field of the sample data are equal for multiple records, therefore I must assume that a higher value in the `id` field means later event. Therefore the `max(id)` per `main_relation_id` would yield the latest even record.

What I would do is to get the `max(id)` per `main_relation_id` within a date range for a particular model in a derived table where `field` is `'publish'` and join this back to your table to find out whether the particular `main_relation_id` was published:

```
select table.main_relation_id
from table
inner join
    (select main_relation_id, max(id) as maxid
     from table
     where date>=... and date<=... and `field`='publish' and model='...'
     group by main_relation_id) t on table.id=t.maxid
where table.new_value=1
```

You need to substitute the filter criteria in place of the `...`. If you would like to get the unpublished data, then replace `table.new_value=1` criterion with `table.new_value=0`.